# Как прописать скрипт jQuery не в header.php, а в CSS?

Tags: jquery, php, wordpress, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, как этот скрипт правильно прописать в файле CSS (тема Wordpress), чтобы он работал. Если прописываю в header.php, возникает конфликт с другим плагином (FancyBox for WordPress) на jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://XXXXXXXXXX/js/jquery.tipTip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://XXXXXXXXXX/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://XXXXXXXXXX/tipTip.css">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
$(".someClass").tipTip({defaultPosition: "right", fadeOut: 89900, activation: "hover"'});
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для таких случаев есть noConflict. Пример использования:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает

Answer (score 1):

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
Так принято подключать JS, в wordpress.

Comment: Будьте добры подробнее, где вставлять
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
Перед подключением jquery или как??